# Preserving Symbology of Published WFS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, wfs, arcgis-10.3, data-interoperability

I published a layer as a WFS on 10.3 server, but when I bring the service into ArcMap via the Data Interoperabiloty Extension, the symbology is lost and the set scale range when to display the data is lost.

How can I preserve these parameters (I did set these parameters prior to publishing)?

Comment: I suspect you will need to use a wms to keep the symbols.

Comment: Does WFS from ArcGIS server support KML output?

Comment: @iant I'd like to use WFS only, but it seems that there is no workaround to keep the symbology.

Comment: WFS is designed to return the geometries, WMS is designed to give you a styled representation of the geometries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @iant:

> you will need to use a wms to keep the symbols

and:

> WFS is designed to return the geometries, WMS is designed to give you
>   a styled representation of the geometries.